# Change TextView value every second? (Android)

Tags: android, timer, textview

Hey guys I'm making an android app and all i need to do is update a TextView box (Id: timeText) +1 every second. There are other posts about this but for some reason nothing is working with my code. I've done this in other IDE's but it just doesn't seem to be working with Android Studio.
Here is what i have:

```
int value = 0;

public MainActivity() {

    final TextView TimeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeText); //giving me error here i think



    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
    {

        public void run()
        {

           value++;

        TimeText.setText(String.valueOf(value));


        }
    };
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0,1000); //1000ms = 1 sec

}
```

I've been trying to solve this all day and any help would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you using a contructor for you MainActivity??

Comment: what is the error? please post your logcat..

Comment: is this an activity???post your full code..have you extended Activity and set the layout correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
    final Runnable refresh = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // update your TextView
        }
    };

    Thread updateThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(refresh);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };      
    updateThread.start();
```